# How to Implement Custom Cache Mechanism with Kotlin Multiplatform(Android, iOS) Ktor Client

Tags: ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on **Kotlin** Multiplatform Project. I used **Ktor** Client for Network calls. I want to cache some request based on some custom logic not based on response header.

`HttpCache` feature provided by `Ktor` is Response Header driven and I am not able to override it because number of Classes is `Internal`.

How can i enable `Ktor` to work with custom cache?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create a custom HttpClient feature that intercepts requests and responses and handling caching

1 Create Cache interface and implement it:

```
interface Cache {
    suspend fun get(request: HttpRequest): HttpResponse?
    suspend fun store(request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse) }

class InMemoryCache : Cache {
    private val cache = mutableMapOf<String, HttpResponse>()

    override suspend fun get(request: HttpRequest): HttpResponse? {
        return cache[request.url.toString()]
    }

    override suspend fun store(request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse) {
        cache[request.url.toString()] = response
    }
}
```

2 Create a custom HttpClient:

```
class CustomCache(private val cache: Cache) {
    class Config {
        lateinit var cache: Cache
    }

    companion object Feature : HttpClientFeature<Config, CustomCache> {
        override val key: AttributeKey<CustomCache> = AttributeKey("CustomCache")

        override fun prepare(block: Config.() -> Unit): CustomCache {
            val config = Config().apply(block)
            return CustomCache(config.cache)
        }

        override fun install(feature: CustomCache, scope: HttpClient) {
            scope.sendPipeline.intercept(HttpSendPipeline.Before) {
                val cachedResponse = cache.get(context.request)
                if (cachedResponse != null) {
                    context.response = cachedResponse
                    finish()
                }
            }

            scope.receivePipeline.intercept(HttpReceivePipeline.After) { response ->
                cache.store(context.request, response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3 Use it in your HttpClient:

```
val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(CustomCache) {
        cache = InMemoryCache()
    }
}
```

After all CustomCache feature will intercept requests and responses, using the provided Cache implementation to store and retrieve cached responses

I'll be glad if it helped you

Comment: The HttpClientFeature interface is renamed to HttpClientPlugin
https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#new-mm